# In OData search.in, if I leave the default delimiter of ', ' or ' ', no value is returned

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm testing out the search api filtering and have a relatedTags parameter that is of type Collection(Edm.String) and when I perform the following filter:

```
relatedTags/any(rt: search.in(rt, 'Tag 3, Tag 2'))
```

which is equivalent to

```
relatedTags/any(rt: rt eq 'Tag 3' or rt eq 'Tag 2')
```

Only the latter will return results where the string array, relatedTags, has either of those values.
If I set the delimiter to `'|'` or `','`:

```
relatedTags/any(rt: search.in(rt, 'Tag 3|Tag 2', '|'))
```

will it return the same as the `eq` example above.

Even specifying the delimiter as `' ,'` or `' '` won't return results.

```
relatedTags/any(rt: search.in(rt, 'Tag 3, Tag 2', ' ,'))
```

The [search.in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-search-in-function) OData language ref page has an example that is the same as what I've written in the first example:

```
Rooms/any(room: room/Tags/any(tag: search.in(tag, 'wifi, tub')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not the same as the example because the values in your comma-separated list have spaces inside them. You need to set the delimiter to just comma, not space or comma:

```
relatedTags/any(rt: search.in(rt, 'Tag 3,Tag 2', ','))
```

You will likely also need to trim whitespace around your tags in order for this to work.

Comment: I see, thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @bruce-johnston Can you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76682830/filtering-on-azure-search-index-not-working which seems to be a similar question