# Filtering on Azure Search Index not working

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

Edit - Removed Issue 1 as I was using the wrong function

**Issue 2**: My actual code gives the 2 below errors (ran independently of each other) that I have tried to detail out without actually getting into the code

**Issue 2.a**

```
Error: () Invalid expression: A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.String' and 'Edm.Int32' for operator kind 'Equal'
```

for the filter arg = ''max_tokens_in_chunk eq 200'

where **max_tokens_in_chunk** is a column in the search index created as `SimpleField(name="max_tokens_in_chunk", type="Edm.String", filterable=True, facetable=True)`

**Issue 2.b**

```
Error: () Invalid expression: Could not find a property named 'Tesla' on type 'search.document'.
Parameter name: $filter
Code:
Message: Invalid expression: Could not find a property named 'Tesla' on type 'search.document'.
Parameter name: $filter
```

for the filter arg  = 'company eq Tesla'

'where company is a column created as `SimpleField(name="company", type="Edm.String", filterable=True, facetable=True)` . I can gaurantee Tesla is present because I printed it out from the Search Index

Comment: For 2 (a), can you please try `''max_tokens_in_chunk eq '200'"`. For 2(b), can you please try with `"company eq 'Tesla'"`.

Comment: Thankyou so much man!. This works. I did not know we have to include 200 and Tesla as a string within a string :) Was new to these type OData filters.    You may ignore the Issue 1 as it was an error on my part - I was filtering in the constructor itself...  Will delete the first half of the question

Comment: Awesome! Added my comment as an answer.

Comment: @GauravMantri If you get a chance, Can you please take a look at the below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76813976/how-to-export-all-some-documents-from-azure-search-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 2(a), the reason you are getting this error is because the field data type is `String` and you are using an integer value for filtering. As mentioned in the comments, please use the following filtering criteria:

```
max_tokens_in_chunk eq '200'
```

Regarding 2(b), I believe the reason you are getting the error is because you are using `Tesla` as is and search service is thinking that it is another field in your index. Again the solution is similar to above:

```
company eq 'Tesla'
```